# Django calculate total price with tax

Tags: python, django, calculator

My math kind of sucks at the moment. I actually have simple calculation that needs to be done for my invoices application.

The models are:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_lenght=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    tax = models.PositiveIntegerField()

Class Invoice(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    date = models.DateField()


class Specification(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I need to have clean way to calculate the total price of the products + the tax to show on the InvoiceDetail template. What is the best way to calculate this?

Answer (score 2):

You can perform addition with `price` and `tax` then `aggregate` the result as total.

```
>>> from django.db.models import F, Sum
>>> Product.objects
      .filter(your_filter_here)
      .aggregate(total=Sum(F('price') + F('tax')), output_field=FloatField())

Output
total: 12345.67
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I eventually came up with a solution on my own though I don't know it is the best one. I added an extra field in the product model which calculated to the product price including tax on save. Then in the specification model I actually needed to add a quantity field and 2 extra fields. One which stored the total price without tax * quantity and an extra field which stored the total price * quantity inlcuding tax. And in my view a just did a for loop that just keeps adding up the the price

Comment: Hi Manu, How did you do this? Was it all done in models.py

Comment: @ManuFebie This can be done in the view.py level, however it is more better to put this on the model with a little different syntax